# Angular ng-options current object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="trip.type" ng-options="type as type.name for type in types" required>
   <option value="" ng-if="!trip.type">Select a type</option>
</select>
```

The above is how I render a select box so a user can select a trip type (Which is an object).

The issue is it does not default to show the type currently assigned to a trip. After reading the documentation it seemed like 'track by type.id' was what I needed which I added to the end of what I current have in ng-options.

This works except once I select a different type it replaces the type object in ng-model with the id string. How can I have it assign the full type object like it does when I do not have 'track by type.id'

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding,  http://jsfiddle.net/1dt2ay14/4/  seems to work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not default to show the type currently assigned to a trip"? This seems to work http://plnkr.co/edit/75DLC923DRDfmtJdrdTA?p=preview